# What is `__stack_pointer` in zig wasm?

Tags: webassembly, zig

Using this in `add.zig`

```
export fn add(a: i32, b: i32) i32 {
    return a + b;
}
```

and compiling with zig 0.11

```bash
zig build-lib add.zig -target wasm32-freestanding -dynamic --export=add -O ReleaseFast
```

then inspecting the output with `wasm2wat add.wasm`, I get the following output:

```
(module
  (type (;0;) (func (param i32 i32) (result i32)))
  (func $add (type 0) (param i32 i32) (result i32)
    local.get 1
    local.get 0
    i32.add)
  (memory (;0;) 16)
  (global $__stack_pointer (mut i32) (i32.const 1048576))
  (export "memory" (memory 0))
  (export "add" (func $add)))
```

Where is this line `(global $__stack_pointer (mut i32) (i32.const 1048576))` coming from? I thought wasm stack was kind of implicit and separate from the memory. The number `1048576` is `2^16 * 16` so it seems to be pointing at the end of the memory.

I was trying to test with clang, and I couldn't get it to generate this.

Answer (score 0):

From [WebAssembly tool conventions GitHub](https://github.com/WebAssembly/tool-conventions/blob/4dd47d204df0c789c23d246bc4496631b5c199c4/DynamicLinking.md?plain=1#L136)

> A WebAssembly dynamic library must obey certain conventions.  In addition to
> the `dylink` section described above a module may import the following globals that will be provided by the dynamic loader:
>
> - ...
> - `env.__stack_pointer` - A mutable `i32` global representing the explicit stack pointer as an offset into the above memory.